# WooCommerce AJAX remove buttons for nav-cart

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I put some Ajax code in my theme to use for Nav Menu cart. It work great when I add product, but;

1- there is No remove button for added product.
2- even if I remove a product from cart, it wouldnt uptdate ajaxify.

how can I add remove added product directly from top menu cart and how make this cart update when a product removed from anywhere.

All of code I used for single page product:

**Header codes:**

```
    <div class="secondary-cart">
    <?php $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    global $woocommerce;
    $item_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; ?>
    <a class="cart-totals" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">Cart (<span><?php echo $item_count; ?></span>)</a>
    <div class="cart-dropdown">
    <div class="cart-dropdown-inner">
    <?php if ($items) { ?>
    <h4>Shopping Bag</h4>
    <?php foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product = $values['data']->post; ?>
    <div class="dropdown-cart-wrap">
    <div class="dropdown-cart-left">
    <?php $variation = $values['variation_id'];
    if ($variation) {   
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $values['variation_id'], 'thumbnail' ); 
    } else {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $values['product_id'], 'thumbnail' ); 
    } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-cart-right">
    <h5><?php echo $_product->post_title; ?></h5>
    <p><strong>Quantity:</strong> <?php echo $values['quantity']; ?></p>
    <?php global $woocommerce;
    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
    $price = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_regular_price', true);
    $sale = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_sale_price', true);
    ?>
        <?php if($sale) { ?>
    <p class="price"><strong>Price:</strong> <del><?php echo $currency; echo $price; ?></del> <?php echo $currency; echo $sale; ?></p>
    <?php } elseif($price) { ?>
    <p class="price"><strong>Price:</strong> <?php echo $currency; echo $price; ?></p>    
    <?php }     ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="dropdown-cart-wrap dropdown-cart-subtotal">
    <div class="dropdown-cart-left">
    <h6>Subtotal</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-cart-right">
    <h6><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url(); ?>
    <div class="dropdown-cart-wrap dropdown-cart-links">
    <div class="dropdown-cart-left dropdown-cart-link">
    <a href="<?php echo $cart_url; ?>">View Cart</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-cart-right dropdown-checkout-link">
    <a href="<?php echo $checkout_url; ?>">Checkout</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <h4>Shopping Bag</h4>
    <div class="dropdown-cart-wrap">
    <p>Your cart is empty.</p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**function code:**

```
    function crispshop_add_cart_single_ajax() {
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $variation_id = $_POST['variation_id'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

        if ($variation_id) {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id );
        } else {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity);
        }

        $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        global $woocommerce;
        $item_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; ?>

        <span class="item-count"><?php echo $item_count; ?></span>

        <h4>Shopping Bag</h4>

        <?php foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product = $values['data']->post; ?>

            <div class="dropdown-cart-wrap">
                <div class="dropdown-cart-left">
                    <?php $variation = $values['variation_id'];
                    if ($variation) {
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $values['variation_id'], 'thumbnail' ); 
                    } else {
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $values['product_id'], 'thumbnail' ); 
                    } ?>
                </div>

                <div class="dropdown-cart-right">
                    <h5><?php echo $_product->post_title; ?></h5>
                    <p><strong>Quantity:</strong> <?php echo $values['quantity']; ?></p>
                    <?php global $woocommerce;
                    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                    $price = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_regular_price', true);
                    $sale = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_sale_price', true);
                    ?>

                    <?php if($sale) { ?>
                        <p class="price"><strong>Price:</strong> <del><?php echo $currency; echo $price; ?></del> <?php echo $currency; echo $sale; ?></p>
                    <?php } elseif($price) { ?>
                        <p class="price"><strong>Price:</strong> <?php echo $currency; echo $price; ?></p>    
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="dropdown-cart-wrap dropdown-cart-subtotal">
            <div class="dropdown-cart-left">
                <h6>Subtotal</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown-cart-right">
                <h6><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></h6>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <?php $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
        $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url(); ?>

        <div class="dropdown-cart-wrap dropdown-cart-links">
            <div class="dropdown-cart-left dropdown-cart-link">
                <a href="<?php echo $cart_url; ?>">View Cart</a>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown-cart-right dropdown-checkout-link">
                <a href="<?php echo $checkout_url; ?>">Checkout</a>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <?php die();
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_crispshop_add_cart_single', 'crispshop_add_cart_single_ajax');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_crispshop_add_cart_single', 'crispshop_add_cart_single_ajax');
```

**Jquery code:**

```
    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).addClass('adding-cart');
        var product_id = jQuery(this).val();
        var variation_id = jQuery('input[name="variation_id"]').val();
        var quantity = jQuery('input[name="quantity"]').val();
        console.log(quantity);
        jQuery('.cart-dropdown-inner').empty();

        if (variation_id != '') {
            jQuery.ajax ({
                url: crispshop_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                type:'POST',
                data:'action=crispshop_add_cart_single&product_id=' + product_id + '&variation_id=' + variation_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,

                success:function(results) {
                    jQuery('.cart-dropdown-inner').append(results);
                    var cartcount = jQuery('.item-count').html();
                    jQuery('.cart-totals span').html(cartcount);
                    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').removeClass('adding-cart');
                    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                    jQuery('.cart-dropdown').addClass('show-dropdown');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        jQuery('.cart-dropdown').removeClass('show-dropdown');
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
        } else {
            jQuery.ajax ({
                url: crispshop_ajax_object.ajax_url,  
                type:'POST',
                data:'action=crispshop_add_cart_single&product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,

                success:function(results) {
                    jQuery('.cart-dropdown-inner').append(results);
                    var cartcount = jQuery('.item-count').html();
                    jQuery('.cart-totals span').html(cartcount);
                    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').removeClass('adding-cart');
                    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                    jQuery('.cart-dropdown').addClass('show-dropdown');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        jQuery('.cart-dropdown').removeClass('show-dropdown');
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Mostafa did you end up working this out? If you could post your solution that would be great.

Comment: I coudnt Find anything